# C# Check if the username is not null or empty nor already taken

Tags: c#, sql, while-loop

As i said, I want to check in the Register that the username isn't null, or empty
nor already taken.

```
    static SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=heres_the_path;Integrated Security=True");
    static string name,pass,email;
    static DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Please help me fix the code, the problem is somewhere here:

```
static bool IsUsernameAlreadyTaken(string name)//Username Checker
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT count(*) FROM Login WHERE Nev='" + name + "'", Con);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1") return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Or in this while loop:

```
static void Register() {  
        Console.WriteLine("What will be your username?");
        while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && IsUsernameAlreadyTaken(name)==false)
        {
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            if (IsUsernameAlreadyTaken(name))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That's already taken");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Why?");
            } 
        }
}
```

Now if I give the program a name which already exist in the database it doesn't tell me that it's already taken, just continuous.

Comment: "the problem is here or here" - Well, which is it?  When you step through this in the debugger, where/how specifically does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: Once you sort the logic/syntax issue you have a new problem: even though you checked that it wasn't taken, it might be taken before you try to add it. So the normal way of doing this, same as when creating files on disk etc, is to try to create the record and see if it works. If it works then it wasn't taken. If it didn't work then it was taken. This requires the database itself to check for duplicate user names - i.e. that it is a key in the db.

Comment: And I'm checking it in the database with the static bool IsUsernameAlreadyTaken, or I'm wrong? @AndersForsgren

Comment: Seeing so many static variables global to the class looks like a code smell. You should try to keep the variable scope as small as possible. Also your SQL code is prone to SQL injection. If someone enters `John'; delete from Login; print 'Bye`, you may lose your entire users table. Also the logic in `Register()` doesn't look fine. Why check twice for `IsNullOrEmpty`? Why display that "Why?"? I suggest you try to re-think, step by step, how your code should behave. I think you added that `string.IsNullOrEmpty` in the `while` condition as a workaround to solve the problem if the name is empty...

Comment: ..but then made the loop exit if the user enters something... Also, why check `IsUsernameAlreadyTaken` BEFORE the user even inputs the name? That doesn't make sense. Again, I suggest you don't try to fix this code but think of a new one from scratch.

Comment: No, the point is you can't make the check first, then the insert after. You should just try it. Explaining here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DUthvf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && IsUsernameAlreadyTaken(name)==false)
```

What you're asking the code to do is this:

1. Check to ensure that `name` is null or empty
2. If it is null or empty, check to see if it is already taken.

Obviously this logic is seriously flawed.

Did you mean this?

```
while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || IsUsernameAlreadyTaken(name)==false)
```

Comment: With your code it's better bot not perfect yet. It says that "That's already taken" but the code continuous and ask for a password. Doesnt start the loop again and ask for a name

Comment: Yeah, you should probably fix that.

Comment: while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || IsUsernameAlreadyTaken(name))

Problem solved

Comment: If `name` has any value that matches an existing user when you call `Register`, the while loop will not be executed. I highly recommend you re-think your logic rather than applying some patch that will give you another bug soon.